# How do I write HTML code in Django's syndication feed framework?

Tags: python, django, xml, rss

I'm using Django's syndication feed framework to generate RSS for my website, referring to [this document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/syndication/)

I have done the work according to the example it provides, the code is similar to the following, I have not made too many changes.

```py
from django.contrib.syndication.views import Feed
from django.urls import reverse
from policebeat.models import NewsItem

class LatestEntriesFeed(Feed):
    title = "Police beat site news"
    link = "/sitenews/"
    description = "Updates on changes and additions to police beat central."

    def items(self):
        return NewsItem.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]

    def item_title(self, item):
        return item.title

    def item_description(self, item):
        return item.description

    # item_link is only needed if NewsItem has no get_absolute_url method.
    def item_link(self, item):
        return reverse('news-item', args=[item.pk])
```

Then I want to add `<a href="test.com">Click to my site</a>` in item_description, I made some minor changes.

```py
    def item_description(self, item):
        description = item.article_description
        description = description + "<a href='test.com'>Click to my site</a>"
        return description
```

But the final generated code is escaped.

```xml
<description>&lt;a href='test.com'&gt;Click to my site&lt;/a&gt;</description>
```

I don't want to be escaped, what should I do?

As far as I know, `<![CDATA[MyInfo]]>` tags need to be added to the HTML code in the xml, similar to the following.

```xml
<![CDATA[<a href='http://test.com'>Click to my site</a>]]>"
```

But I don't know how to do this in Django framework.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the escaped version is correct - it ensures that HTML tags are not confused with RSS tags. Have you tested it with an RSS reader?

Comment: @gasman Thanks, I just tried opening it with Feedbro and found that it was recognized correctly, so maybe this issue can be overlooked.
The problem I'm having with the issue occurs when "opening rss link (XML)", which seems to be different from the usual <! [CDATA[MyInfo]]> tag, won't this cause compatibility problems in different RSS readers?